PHP exec() command not working as expected
I have a PHP process (backup-generic) that builds and then executes a command to perform backups on various directories.  The net result of this command, when I execute for a particular user's home directory is:
zip --symlinks --recurse-paths --quiet /usr/local/backups/home_dennis-daily-2024-09-19.zip '/home/dennis' -x '.DS_Store' -x '._*' -x '/home/delovelady/.vscode-server/bin/*/node/*' -x '/home/delovelady/.vscode-server/data/*' 2>&1

This command is echoed into the log just prior to execution as such:
$lov->writeLogLine( [ 'Executing command: %s', $backupCmd ] ) ;
$rc = 0 ;
$OK = exec($backupCmd, $output, $rc) ;

This creates a huge file that contains all the vscode stuff we tried to omit via -x swiches.  But if I copy that very command from the log, and then execute it as-is, in a terminal, the result is exactly what I wanted (files below specified vscode directories are omitted and the .zip file is 300MB smaller).
This led me to believe that PHP was (effectively) removing the apostrophes from the command.  So I made this little test script:
<?php
$rc = 0 ;
$output = [] ;
$result = exec("ls '*' 2>&1", $output, $rc) ;
printf("Result code %d returned from command: %s\n", $rc, $command) ;
foreach ($output as $line) {
    printf("    > %s\n", $line) ;
}
printf("All done.\n") ;

But when I ran this script, it did exactly what the command line would have done: objected to the file-not found (ls -l '*' with apostrophes).  So I'm quite confused about what is going on here.
Given that result, why would there be a fundamental difference between PHP's use of exec(command) and the execution of the very same command from a shell (ksh, in this case)* ?

I would think the use of ksh versus /bin/sh versus a multitude of other shell solutions would make no difference in the interpretation of this particular command.  ksh just happens to be my shell of choice.

(As an aside, there's an abundance of discussion all over StackOverflow and elsewhere, addressing just how to exclude files and directories from .zip backups.  I must say I have been caught up in trial and error based on that.  But the confusion may not all be associated with a training issue.  It seems there may be more going on here than meets the eye.)
** UPDATE: Requested code**
For the include list and the exclude list, the PHP script contains a function (globFileList()) that handles the escaping/quotation of each file parameter.  It is passed a two-element array.  In the above example, the array passed for exclusion is:
[
    "/home/delovelady/.vscode-server/bin/*/node/* => "noglob"
  , "/home/delovelady/.vscode-server/data/*" => "noglob"
}

The function code is:
function globFileList(array $list) : array {
    global $lov, $pdo, $ini ;

    $globbedList = [] ;
    foreach ($list as $fileOrDir => $onOrOff) {
        if ($onOrOff === 'noglob') { // use as an absolute, not a glob
            $globbedList[] = escapeshellarg($fileOrDir) ;
        } elseif ($onOrOff) { // For each file/directory that's tagged as true/yes/on/...
            $files = glob($fileOrDir) ;
            if (count($files) > 0) {
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    $globbedList[] = escapeShellArg($file) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $globbedList ;
}

// elsewhere....

foreach ($inclusions as $include)
    $backupCmd .= ' ' . $include ;
foreach ($exclusions as $exclude)
    $backupCmd .= ' -x' . $exclude ;

ENVIRONMENT:
> cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.5 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
delovelady@web:/home/delovelady   09/19 14:57:29

> ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+m/1.0.0-beta.2 2021-12-17
delovelady@web:/home/delovelady   09/19 14:57:37

    > zip --version
Copyright (c) 1990-2008 Info-ZIP - Type 'zip "-L"' for software license.
This is Zip 3.0 (July 5th 2008), by Info-ZIP.
Currently maintained by E. Gordon.  Please send bug reports to
the authors using the web page at www.info-zip.org; see README for details.

Latest sources and executables are at ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip,
as of above date; see http://www.info-zip.org/ for other sites.

Compiled with gcc 11.2.0 for Unix (Linux ELF).

Zip special compilation options:
        USE_EF_UT_TIME       (store Universal Time)
        BZIP2_SUPPORT        (bzip2 library version 1.0.8, 13-Jul-2019)
            bzip2 code and library copyright (c) Julian R Seward
            (See the bzip2 license for terms of use)
        SYMLINK_SUPPORT      (symbolic links supported)
        LARGE_FILE_SUPPORT   (can read and write large files on file system)
        ZIP64_SUPPORT        (use Zip64 to store large files in archives)
        UNICODE_SUPPORT      (store and read UTF-8 Unicode paths)
        STORE_UNIX_UIDs_GIDs (store UID/GID sizes/values using new extra field)
        UIDGID_NOT_16BIT     (old Unix 16-bit UID/GID extra field not used)
        [encryption, version 2.91 of 05 Jan 2007] (modified for Zip 3)

Encryption notice:
        The encryption code of this program is not copyrighted and is
        put in the public domain.  It was originally written in Europe
        and, to the best of our knowledge, can be freely distributed
        in both source and object forms from any country, including
        the USA under License Exception TSU of the U.S. Export
        Administration Regulations (section 740.13(e)) of 6 June 2002.

Zip environment options:
             ZIP:  [none]
          ZIPOPT:  [none]


Why are you using quotes in the first place?

Rather than inspect each character to determine if it is a wildcard, the script uses escapeshellarg() against each exclude/include argument.  According to the zip documentation: "To have wildcards apply to files in subdirectories when recursing on Unix and similar systems where the shell does wildcard substitution, either escape all wildcards  or  put  all arguments with wildcards in quotes"

@Olivier The exec() command runs the command in a shell.

Can you show the PHP code you're using to generate $backupCmd?

Consolidating prior comments into one (prior will be deleted).  @Barmar I agree there's nothing shell specific in the command, should work with any shell.  Can you tell me why the source code that builds the command is important?  I'd like to keep the question to the point if possible.

I've deleted all those other comments. I'd like to see how you're quoting things in the generation code.

Ideally you should use escapeshellarg() to quote/escape each argument, then concatenate them together into the command.

@Barmar: The code addressing your concern has been added to the question.  (I realize that the "if count()" code is unnecessary.)

Your code will create -x'._*', but the command line you show has a space after -x. So I don't think that's the actual command that comes from this code.

Pardon me, but you're picking nits, @Barmar and drifting from the original question (which was my fear).  Yes, I changed this code yexterday to exclude the space based on this within "man zip" (whitespace removed by me): "If there is no space between -x and the pattern, just one value is assumed (no list): zip -r foo foo -x*.o"  Result did not change.

Yes, I'm picking nits, because details often matter. While that by itself might not make a difference, it helps if we can see exactly what's going on when trying to debug code. Bugs often come from little typos (e.g. writing = instead of ==).

I wonder if adding --show-command and inspecting the output might help? That should give you what zip thinks you said without actually doing any work.
